# Inconsistent behavior of `mktemp` crate in Rust

Tags: rust

If I call `.to_path_buf()` immediately after `expect`, the temporary directory will not be created. Is this a bug or a Rust feature?

```
extern crate mktemp;                                                                                                                                                                                        

use std::path::Path;                                                                                                                                                                                        

fn main() {                                                                                                                                                                                                 
    let temp_dir = mktemp::Temp::new_dir().expect("Failed to create a temp directory");                                                                                                                     
    let temp_dir_path = temp_dir.to_path_buf();                                                                                                                                                             
    println!("tmp path exists: {}", Path::exists(&temp_dir_path));                                                                                                                                          

    let temp_dir_path = mktemp::Temp::new_dir().expect("Failed to create a temp directory").to_path_buf();                                                                                                  
    println!("tmp path exists: {}", Path::exists(&temp_dir_path));                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Which outputs:

```
tmp path exists: true
tmp path exists: false
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know, but I wonder if there's something in [the `mktemp` documentation](https://docs.rs/mktemp/0.3.1/mktemp/) about this...

> Once the variable goes out of scope, the underlying file system resource is removed.

You're not storing the `Temp` in a variable, so it goes out of scope immediately.  It's creating the directory and then immediately destroying it.

Comment: Yep, seems typical RAII behavior to me: to ensure that the temporary directory (a resource) is cleaned-up, its lifetime is tied to that of a variable in the program. Of course, it's not 100% guarantee (you can use `mem::forget`...), but it's really helpful to avoid running out of file-descriptors in general.